# How to fix the "Table doesn't exist" error error when running 'php artisan migrate' command?

Tags: laravel, database-migration, laravel-7, artisan-migrate

I have a project on which I need to run `php artisan migrate`. It should be easy but I am getting an error:

> php artisan migrate
>
> Illuminate\Database\QueryException
>
> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
> 'skz.master_courses' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from
> `master_courses` where `date_from` > 2021-06-01 and
> `master_courses`.`deleted_at` is null order by `date_from` asc limit
> 1)

I don't understand where the select command comes from. Does anybody know where is it from?

Comment: check do you skz database created in mysql

Comment: Skz database is empty. Dont understand why migrate script call select.

Comment: check for  capital S or s .if its perfect then check any query executing in service provider etc.. this is just my guessing

Comment: YES you are right. AppSeviceProvider.php contains select in boot() method. Create an answer I can accept.

Comment: okay. i will ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error usually throw when database doesn't exist in mysql.

But in your case, database exists in mysql server.So you it look like your application executing select query in any one of the service provider `boot()` method

```
public function boot()
{
          
}
```

So you might need to stop query execution till  migration completes.